# RxDart listen not working after Future delay

Tags: rxdart

I'm trying to use `autoConnect` in RxDart, whose description is

> Returns an Observable that automatically connects (at most once) to this ConnectableObservable when the first Observer subscribes.

```
  Observable<int> o = Observable.range(1, 2).publish().autoConnect();

  o.listen((v) { print('Observer 1: $v'); });
  o.listen((v) { print('Observer 2: $v'); });
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(microseconds: 1));
  o.listen((v) { print('Observer 3: $v'); });
```

Output:

```
Subscriber 1: 1
Subscriber 2: 1
Subscriber 1: 2
Subscriber 2: 2
```

As you can see, no output from the third Observer.

The similar output also happens if I use `ConnectableObservable` and put the `.connect()` call before the delay and also while using `refCount()`

But for `refCount`, I think it's expected as the description is:

> Returns an Observable that stays connected to this ConnectableObservable
>    as long as there is at least one subscription to this
>    ConnectableObservable.

I don't why `autoConnect` behaves like `refCount` (what are the differences between them)
And also why the Observer after delay is unable to listen